# Extruding along a path

Tags: graphics, plotting

I'm trying to render a 3D image of a path by extruding a circular cross-section along the path, to create a "snake-like" path.

Here is an image I found to illustrate:

[image: tube]

I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to do this?

I just found the `Tube` command; now I need to find a way to turn a set of points into a curve. Basically, I need to find the necessary control points for a `BezierCurve` or a `BSplineCurve` to fit a set of `{x, y}` coordinates.

Can the `Interpolation` with the `Spline` method be used to generate a spline from a set of points?

Comment: Your picture is 3D - so do you mean a set of **{x,y,z}** coordinates?

Comment: My data is 2D, I just did {x, y, 0} so that it would be in the x-y plane.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In Mathematica 7 or 8, you can just use [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tube.html).  Please see the docs for many, many examples.

Example:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[x], Sin[x], x/5}, {x, 0, 15}] /. 
  Line -> (Tube[#, 0.2] &), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much, I eventually found the Tube command but I had no idea you could replace the line in the parametric plot with a tube so easily! You get an upvote, you would also get one from my girlfriend who's work I was doing but she doesn't have an account.

Answer (score 35):

This question has been nicely addressed by the previous answers, so I'll just write about a method you can use if you want your tube to have *custom* cross-sections; or, like in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9258), you need to have the tube as a bunch of `Polygon[]`s.

```
(* Pixar method; http://jcgt.org/published/0006/01/01/ *)
orthogonalDirections[{p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ}] := Module[{s, w, w1, xx, yy, zz},
     {xx, yy, zz} = Normalize[p2 - p1];
     s = 2 UnitStep[zz] - 1; w = -1/(s + zz); w1 = xx yy w;
     {{1 + s w xx^2, s w1, -s xx}, {w1, s + w yy^2, -yy}}]

orthogonalDirections[{p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ, p3_?VectorQ}] := Module[{d, u, v},
     {u, v} = Normalize /@ {p3 - p2, p1 - p2};
     If[Chop[Norm[u - v] Norm[u + v]] != 0,
        d = (u + v)/2; Normalize /@ {d, Cross[u, d]},
        orthogonalDirections[{p1, p2}]]]

extend[cs_, q_, d_, nrms_] :=
cs + Outer[Times, First[LinearSolve[Transpose[Prepend[-nrms, d]],
                                    q - Transpose[cs]]], d]

(* for custom cross-sections *)
crossSection[pointList_?MatrixQ, r_, csList_?MatrixQ] := Module[{p1, p2},
     {p1, p2} = Take[pointList, 2];
     (p1 + #) & /@ (r csList.orthogonalDirections[{p1, p2}])] /; 
Last[Dimensions[pointList]] == 3 && Last[Dimensions[csList]] == 2

(* for circular cross-sections *)
crossSection[pointList_?MatrixQ, r_, n_Integer] := 
 crossSection[pointList, r, Composition[Through, {Cos, Sin}] /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n]]

(* approximate vertex normals, for a smooth appearance *)
vertNormals[vl_ /; ArrayQ[vl, 3, NumericQ]] := Block[{mdu, mdv, msh},
    msh = ArrayPad[#, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, "Extrapolated", InterpolationOrder -> 2] & /@
          Transpose[vl, {2, 3, 1}];
    mdu = ListCorrelate[{{1, 0, -1}}/2, #, {{-2, 1}, {2, -1}}, 0] & /@ msh;
    mdv = ListCorrelate[{{-1}, {0}, {1}}/2, #, {{1, -2}, {-1, 2}}, 0] & /@ msh;
    MapThread[Composition[Normalize, Cross], Transpose[{mdu, mdv}, {1, 4, 2, 3}], 2]]

MakePolygons[vl_ /; ArrayQ[vl, 3, NumericQ], OptionsPattern[{"Normals" -> True}]] :=
Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]]}, 
       GraphicsComplex[Apply[Join, vl], 
                       Polygon[Flatten[Apply[Join[Reverse[#1], #2] &, 
                       Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]],
                                 {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}], 1]], 
                       If[TrueQ[OptionValue["Normals"] /. Automatic -> True], 
                          VertexNormals -> Apply[Join, vertNormals[vl]], 
                          Unevaluated[]]]]

Options[TubePolygons] = {"Normals" -> True, "Scale" -> 1.};
TubePolygons[path_?MatrixQ, cs : (_Integer | _?MatrixQ), OptionsPattern[]] :=
With[{p3 = PadRight[path, {Automatic, 3}]},
     MakePolygons[FoldList[Function[{p, t}, 
                                    extend[p, t[[2]], t[[2]] - t[[1]],
                                           orthogonalDirections[t]]], 
                           crossSection[p3, OptionValue["Scale"], cs], 
                           Partition[p3, 3, 1, {1, 2}, {}]], 
                  "Normals" -> OptionValue["Normals"]]]
```

Try it out:

```
path = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot3D[BSplineFunction[
       {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, -1}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 1, -1}}][u] // Evaluate,
     {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];

cs = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[
     BSplineFunction[{{0., 0.}, {0.25, 0.}, {0.5, 0.125}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0., 0.25}},
                     SplineClosed -> True][u] // Evaluate,
                 {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: B-spline tube with B-spline cross section]

Of course, you can elect to have a circular cross section, as is usual:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, 20, "Scale" -> .2]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: B-spline tube with circular cross section]

Answer (score 27):

I see you mentioned splines in your question. Your picture is 3D, but you used 2D {x,y} coordinates in the question. This little example uses a random set of control points and emphasizes the 3D nature of the `Tube` and {x,y,z} coordinates:

```
points = RandomReal[1, {20, 3}]; 
Export["tube.gif",
   Table[
      Graphics3D[
         {Orange, Specularity[White, 100], Tube[BSplineCurve[points], .03]},
         Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True,
         ViewAngle -> .25, 
         ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[a, {0, 0, 1}][{3, 0, 3}]], 
      {a, 0, 2 Pi, .1}
   ]]
```

[image: tube through random points]

Comment: @BrettChampion Thanks for the code edit ;-)

Answer (score 22):

The disadvantage of using `BSplineCurve` is that generally speaking, the curve doesn't go through the control points. If you want the curve to be both smooth and go through the test points, you could `Interpolation` with `Method -> "Spline"` instead. For example

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {30, 3}];
interp = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, pts], Method -> "Spline"]
```

You could then use Szabolcs's method to plot `interp` and replace the line with a tube:

```
pl = ParametricPlot3D[interp[x], {x, 1, Length[pts]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 2 Length[pts],
  PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All] /. {Line[a_] :> Tube[a, .05]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To show that the control points actually lie on the curve:

```
Show[pl, Graphics3D[{White, Sphere[#, .08] & /@ pts}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `BSplineCurve` you would get

```
Graphics3D[{{Darker[Blue], Tube[BSplineCurve[pts], .05]}, {White, 
   Sphere[#, .08] & /@ pts}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "The disadvantage of using `BSplineCurve[]` is that generally speaking, the curve doesn't go through the control points." - on the other hand, [it is not too hard to build an interpolating B-spline.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineCurve.html#968466)

Answer (score 21):

Not directly related to question, but rather in addition to J.M.'s answer, here's a simple method to extrude any cross section (not just a circle) when you have a differentiable path:

```
(* First get the curve for the path, in this case the trefoil knot. *)
path = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]

(* Now define the shape of the cross section, in this case a deltoid. *)
crosssection = {2 Cos[#] + Cos[2 #], 2 Sin[#] - Sin[2 #], 0} &

(* Plot the extruded path. First rotate the cross section to be 
   perpendicular to the tangent of the path, and then translate. *)
ParametricPlot3D[
  path[u] + 1/8 RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, path'[u]}].crosssection[v],
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False, MaxRecursion -> 3
]
```

[image: Trefoil knot extruded with a deltoid]

Comment: Could you tell me if I can use polygon as crossection? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/moving-polygon-on-path-curve-to-create-3d-shape

Answer (score 18):

`Tube` is the right thing to use here. Increase `n` to smoothly interpolate your curve, and `r` to control the thickness of your circle.

```
n = 280;
r = .15;
data = Table[{Cos[u] Sin[u^.3], Sin[u] Cos[u^.2], u/10}, {u, 0, 45,45/(n - 1)}];
Graphics3D[{CapForm[None], 
Tube[BSplineCurve[data], Table[r, {i, Length@data}]]},
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: tube]

If you want a function:

```
Extrude[{x_, y_, z_}, {t_, Start_, End_}, Discretization_, Radius_] := 
Module[{data3d},
       data3d =Table[{x, y, z}, {t, Start,End, (End - Start)/(Discretization - 1)}];
       Graphics3D[{CapForm[None],Tube[BSplineCurve[data3d],
       Table[Radius, {i, Length@data3d}]]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
      ];
```

The following will generate the same extrusion as the graphics:

```
Extrude[{Cos[u] Sin[u^.3], Sin[u] Cos[u^.2], u/10}, {u, 0, 45}, 280, .1]
```

Answer (score 14):

I am writing this answer as a separate supplement to my previous one, and also as an expansion of Teake's answer.

Teake's answer features one possible solution to the problem of constructing a tube from a given path and cross section. It works for a lot of space curves, but can fail in some cases.

For instance, consider this perturbed [clothoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html):

```
path[t_] := With[{b = 1/2},
                 {FresnelS[t/Sqrt[1 + b^2]], FresnelC[t/Sqrt[1 + b^2]], b/Sqrt[1 + b^2] t}]
```

[image: perturbed clothoid]

and say we want to make a tube with a circular cross section out of it:

```
circ[u_] := {Cos[u], Sin[u]}/15;
```

Let's try Teake's solution (where I had rearranged it into an equivalent form):

```
ParametricPlot3D[path[u] + circ[v].Most[RotationMatrix[{path'[u], {0, 0, 1}}]] // Evaluate,
                 {u, -5, 5}, {v, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> {75, 45}]
```

[image: tube with gaps]

Oh no! All those breaks!

One could try adding `Exclusions -> None`, but the tube still looks somewhat pinched at those places.

One could also try the more conventional method of using the Frenet-Serret frame to make the tube:

```
nbv[t_] = Rest[Last[FrenetSerretSystem[path[t], t]]];

ParametricPlot3D[path[t] + circ[u].nbv[t] // Evaluate, {t, -5, 5}, {u, 0, 2 π}, 
                 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> {75, 45}]
```

[image: Frenet-Serret tube]

but that also produces a tube with a kink.

What to do?

The solution is to use the [Bishop frame](https://doi.org/10.2307/2319846) to set up the required local coordinate system around the space curve. Unlike the other approaches, the vectors produced by the Bishop frame are guaranteed not to collapse, which would lead to the pinches and gaps in the previously produced tubes.

Adapting Henrik's code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167614) to this situation, we have the following routine:

```
plotTube[f_, cs_, t0_: 0, {t_, tra__}, {u_, ura__},
         opts : OptionsPattern[{NDSolve, ParametricPlot3D}]] := 
    Module[{bf, bi, b0, nf, no, n0, s, ta, ts, w, w1, xx, yy, zz, T, γ, κ},
           γ = Function[t, f];
           (* unit tangent vector *)
           T = Function[t, Evaluate[Normalize[γ'[t]]]];
           (* curvature vector *)
           κ = Function[t, Evaluate[(γ''[t] - (γ''[t].T[t]) T[t])/Norm[γ'[t]]^2]];
           (* Pixar method; http://jcgt.org/published/0006/01/01/ *)
           ts = T[t0]; {xx, yy, zz} = ts;
           s = 2 UnitStep[zz] - 1; w = -1/(s + zz); w1 = xx yy w;
           n0 = {1 + s w xx^2, s w1, -s xx}; b0 = {w1, s + w yy^2, -yy};
           (* Bishop frame *)
           {nf, bf} = NDSolveValue[{ta'[t] == Norm[γ'[t]]
                                    {no[t].κ[t], bi[t].κ[t]}.{no[t], bi[t]},
                                    no'[t] == -Norm[γ'[t]] ta[t] no[t].κ[t],
                                    bi'[t] == -Norm[γ'[t]] ta[t] bi[t].κ[t],
                                    ta[t0] == ts, no[t0] == n0, bi[t0] == b0},
                                   {no, bi}, {t, tra},
                                   Method -> {"OrthogonalProjection",
                                              Dimensions -> {3, 3}},
                                   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolveValue]]];
           ParametricPlot3D[γ[t] + cs.{nf[t], bf[t]}, {t, tra}, {u, ura},
                            Method -> Automatic, 
                            Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot3D]]], 
                            Mesh -> False]]
```

where I use [orthogonal projection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOrthogonalProjection.html) to enforce the orthogonality of the Bishop frame.

This gives a pretty nice tube:

```
plotTube[path[t], circ[u], {t, -5, 5}, {u, 0, 2 π}, PlotPoints -> {75, 45}]
```

[image: tube, Bishop-style]

A more elaborate example:

```
plotTube[{3 Cos[t]/4 - Cos[3 t]/2, Sin[t]/4 + Sin[3 t]/2, Sin[5 t]/4},
         (2 + Cos[3 u])/3 {Cos[u], Sin[u]}/30, {t, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, 2 π},
         PlotPoints -> 55]
```

[image: square knot with threefold-symmetric cross section]