# Convert Graphics3D containing BSpline to polygon primitives for export to 3DS?

Tags: graphics, export

`Graphics3D[]` objects created with BSpline functions will not export to 3DS format, which only supports the more basic primitives. Is there any straightforward way to get at an underlying polygon representation of the `BSplineSurface[]` graphics "primitive" (in quotes because its not very primitive)?

An example is the final 'pipe' example in the documentation [ref/BSplineSurface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineSurface.html#127549356). If you try `Export["Pipe.3ds", %]`, you get an error.

In my particular case I'm creating arbitrary 'surface of revolution' objects as per the "Potter's Wheel" demonstration, where the cross section is determined by a BSpline with dynamic control points. That works fine, but then I need export the resulting objects to another program.

Comment: Please include a sample code snippet -- you will get faster/better answers that way.

Comment: Good question. Would you mind providing an example of a surface you try to export? That would make playing around that much easier.

Comment: Under most definitions of straightforward, I don't believe there is. You may have to write a program that converts it into graphics primitives.

Answer (score 26):

I don't know what you'll count as "straightforward", but...

```
(* data for B-spline surface, from example in docs *)
pts = {{{0.5, 0, -0.5}, {0, 0, -0.5}, {0, 1, -0.5}, {0.5, 1, -0.5}, {1, 1, -0.5},
        {1, 0, -0.5}, {0.5, 0, -0.5}}, 
       {{0.5, 0, 0.7}, {0, 0, 0.7}, {0, 1, 0.7}, {0.5, 1, 0.7}, {1, 1, 0.7},
        {1, 0, 0.7}, {0.5, 0, 0.7}}, 
   {{0.5, 0, 0.9}, {0, 0, 0.9}, {0, 1, 1.5}, {0.5, 1, 1.5}, {1, 1, 1.5},
    {1, 0, 0.9}, {0.5, 0, 0.9}}, 
   {{0.5, -0.1, 1}, {0, -0.1, 1}, {0, 0.5, 2}, {0.5, 0.5, 2}, {1, 0.5, 2},
    {1, -0.1, 1}, {0.5, -0.1, 1}}, 
   {{0.5, -0.3, 1}, {0, -0.3, 1}, {0, -0.3, 2}, {0.5, -0.3, 2},
    {1, -0.3, 2}, {1, -0.3, 1}, {0.5, -0.3, 1}}, 
   {{0.5, -1.5, 1}, {0, -1.5, 1}, {0, -1.5, 2}, {0.5, -1.5, 2},
    {1, -1.5, 2}, {1, -1.5, 1}, {0.5, -1.5, 1}}};
w = {{1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1}, {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1},
     {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1}, {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1},
     {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1}, {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1}};
uk = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
vk = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};

Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[pts, SplineKnots -> {uk, vk}, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                          SplineWeights -> w, SplineClosed -> {False, True}]] /. 
           bs : BSplineSurface[pts_?ArrayQ, opts___] :> 
           Module[{bsf = BSplineFunction[pts, opts]}, 
                  Cases[Normal[Cases[ParametricPlot3D[bsf[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}],
                        _GraphicsComplex, ∞]], _Polygon, ∞]]
```

[image: polygons for the B-spline surface, adaptive sampling]

You can check that the output is composed entirely of `Polygon[]` objects. If need be, you can tweak the options within `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

---

From the comments, it was asked how one might do a version where the sampling is uniform and the polygons are quadrilaterals. The old version of `ParametricPlot3D[]` did something like that. Here's how I'd emulate it:

```
MakePolygons[vl_] /; ArrayQ[vl, 3] := Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]]}, 
  GraphicsComplex[Apply[Join, vl], Polygon[Flatten[Apply[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] &, 
                  Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]], {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
                        {2}], 1]]]]

Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[pts, SplineKnots -> {uk, vk}, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                          SplineWeights -> w, SplineClosed -> {False, True}]] /. 
           bs : BSplineSurface[pts_?ArrayQ, opts___] :> 
           Module[{bsf = BSplineFunction[pts, opts], upts = 30, vpts = 18}, 
                  Cases[Normal[MakePolygons[
                        Table[bsf[u, v], {u, 0, 1, 1/(upts - 1)}, {v, 0, 1, 1/(vpts - 1)}]
                        ]], _Polygon, ∞]]
```

[image: polygons for the B-spline surface, uniform sampling]

Comment: Wicked! How´d you arrive at that one?

Comment: Well, I know that `BSplineSurface[]` and `BSplineCurve[]` are always convertible in terms of `BSplineFunction[]`... then, it was a matter of extracting polygons from `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Comment: My impression is the the whole `BSpline` surface stuff is still a bit standalone (not to say orphaned).

Comment: Maybe we should ask Yu-Sung about that...

Comment: Definitely...he did show rather more advanced stuff some time ago which allegedly did not make the release...

Comment: @J.M. Can we also tweak how the surface mesh is done ? Suppose if one wants to specify the minimum surface area the smallest triangle can have or if somebody wants a uniform quad mesh. That will be very helpful...

Comment: @Plato, "...if somebody wants a uniform quad mesh..." - that requires a bit more programming effort, but it's definitely doable (I'll edit this answer for that case if there's interest). For your first case, I don't know how to hijack the adaptive algorithm used by `ParametricPlot3D[]`. Sorry.

Comment: @J.M. Some more interesting tricks from your bag will be very much appreciated on this context. Please take your time to edit the answer for any further update. Uniform quad mesh for arbitrary 3D MMA `BSpline` will be a sure treat. I asked similar question once..

Comment: @J.M. In the mean time should I ask a question titled "hijack the adaptive algorithm" used in 3D meshing....;) we are not getting many eye opening tricky questions in the forum recently...

Comment: Sounds like a neat plan, @Plato. :)

Comment: @J.M. here is some control over the adaptive alg. : `ParametricPlot3D[bsf[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotPoints -> {20, 30}]` Here `MaxRecursion->0` switches it off and the PlotPoints can be a List.

Comment: @rueben, I know about that bit, but Plato was asking about controlling the size of the triangles, and I don't know which options to tweak for those.

Comment: @J.M. well the only way to do that is by using more plot points. To my knowledge there is no way to directly influence the triangle areas. - You could use TetGenLink` for that perhaps.

Comment: @J.M., perhaps it is possible to use the bounding box and the plot points to roughly estimate the resulting triangle size. Never tried that though.

Comment: @ruebenko How do you suggest to use TetGenLink to control the triangle area of the surface mesh if we take the above tube example? How to automatically define the required TetGen interpretable geometry input from the spline based triangular mesh of the tube (or any complex 3d geometry) that J.M creates elegantly..?

Comment: @PlatoManiac, sorry it took me a while to come back to this. You need to create a closed surface spline, extract the GraphicsComplex (not the Normal[] of it!) and those coords and incidents can be feed to TetGen. Now, I have tried this for this example and unfortunately there is issue with creating the tetrahedralization; TetGen reports open facets. If you want to I can send you the code. Write me an email at ruebenko AT wolfram.com

Comment: @ruebenko Thx! I sent you an email...

Comment: Well, thanks J.M., that was brilliant. I had no idea `BSplineFunction` produced such a different output to `BSplineSurface` under the hood. It's not related to this question, I think, but my my pipeline is to export to 3DS, import to SketchUp, and then immediately export to Collada. When I do that, the interior faces of the pipe are transparent, which creates a very odd-looking Collada file! This happens even if I specify something like `FaceForm[Blue, Red]` in Mathematica's code. The inside and outside are colored fine in Mathematica, but in SketchUp the interior has lost all texture.

Comment: Sounds like a different problem altogether, @Gareth. Does this oddness persist if you use the version with uniform sampling instead of the one with adaptive sampling?

Comment: Interesting. When I append `FaceForm[Blue, Red]` to the uniform sampling version, by putting it inside the `Graphics3D` and before the redefined `BSplineSurface` argument, it produces the opposite coloring: the _inside_ of the pipe is blue and the outside red. When exported as 3DS, and then imported into SketchUp, the inside stays blue and the outside is now transparent. Which, when rendered, looks _really_ strange. It's not the color per se -- it seems to be the 'front'/'back' attribute given to a polygon.

Comment: Very peculiar, @Gareth. It seems to be something screwy in the exporting... maybe ask a new question?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why your custom `BSplineSurface` creates polygons whose 'front' surface ends up on the inside of the shape, but no luck yet. For my application, the simplicity of the uniform sampling will be much better, and if I can get the front/back thing sorted out, I'll be fine, because my shapes will be closed, so a transparent inside won't  matter!

Comment: Ah, I now know why, @Gareth. From the docs for `FaceForm[]`: "The front face of a polygon is defined to be the one for which the corners as you specify them are in counterclockwise order (right-hand rule)." I modified the definition for `MakePolygons[]` to match this; try it now.