# Difference of old Graphics`Graphics3D`ListSurfacePlot3D and the current ListSurfacePlot3D

Tags: graphics, plotting

Consider the following example data which creates the lines of a cylinder

```
data=Table[{Cos[phi],Sin[phi],z},{phi,0,2Pi,.1},{z,0,1,.1}];
Graphics3D[{RandomChoice[ColorData[3,"ColorList"]],Line[#]}&/@data]
```

[image]

The coloring indicates the structure of `data` which is a *list of lines* where with lines I mean a list of `{x,y,z}` coordinates. Therefore, `data` is of dimension `{63, 11, 3}`: 63 lines where each line as 11 points.

With the legacy package of older *Mathematica* versions it was now possible to create the surface of the cylinder by

```
Needs ["Graphics` Graphics3D `"]
ListSurfacePlot3D[data]
```

If you look on the usage of the built-in `ListSurfacePlot3D` function you see that it can only take a list of 3D points and not such a structured tensor as `data`. When you then try it anyway, you get a surprising result:

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[data]
```

[image]

**Question:** is it possible to create the surface of the cylinder like the old version of `ListSurfacePlot3D` did?

On this simple examples, a call to

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

helps. Unfortunately, for my [original data here](http://quaternions.blog.163.com/blog/static/206082147201331173925194/), this doesn't work. You can recreate the error by shearing the cylinder data

```
data = Table[
   {Cos[phi] + 2 z, z, Sin[phi] + z}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {z, -2, 
    2, .1}];
Graphics3D[{RandomChoice[ColorData[3, "ColorList"]], Line[#]} & /@ 
   data]
ListSurfacePlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

and then you get

[image]

Comment: The link provided doesn't explain the problem your trying to solve.  Please edit and explain that in your question above.  thank you

Comment: @chuy Please see my edit

Comment: really cool edit, sorry for my lazy work, I'm freshman of this website, I'll take some time to get familar with the comuunity about learn to  edit and express problems clearly.

Comment: @HyperGroups Welcome to Mma.SE!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I tried was to `Flatten` your data, so that it is a flat list of 3D coordinates. When you take your simple cylinder example and apply for instance a shearing transformation, you see, that you cannot rely on what `ListSurfacePlot3D` is doing.

Not only that it does not reconstruct your whole cylinder points, furthermore it gets really messy when the shearing kicks in:

```
With[{data = Flatten[Table[
     {Cos[phi], Sin[phi], z}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}, {z, -1, 1, .1}], 1]},

 Manipulate[
  Show[
     ListSurfacePlot3D[#],
     Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[1], Red, Point[#]}],
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PlotRangePadding -> .5
     ] &[
   ShearingTransform[phi, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}][data]],
  {phi, 0, Pi/2}]
 ]
```

[image]

If you want to have the behavior of the old `ListSurfacePlot3D` back, you could investigate in the `AddOns/LegacyPackages/Graphics` directory of a version 8 installation and extract the important code:

```
MakePolygons[vl_List] := 
 Module[{l = vl, l1 = Map[RotateLeft, vl], mesh}, 
  mesh = {l, l1, RotateLeft[l1], RotateLeft[l]};
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {1}];
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {2}];
  Polygon /@ Transpose[Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mesh]]]

ListSurfacePlot3DOld[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics3D[MakePolygons[data], 
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListSurfacePlot3D]]]]
```

And now, everything should work as expected

```
ListSurfacePlot3DOld[data, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I, for one, downvoted the question. I don't consider my decision _annoying_, but I feel the question really is.

Comment: @belisarius So it is obvious and not worth investigating, why `ListSurfacePlot3D` changed its behavior? Because this is what the question is: How handled the old function tensors of dimensions {n1,n2,3} and why can the new function only handle tensors of dimensions {n,3}?

Comment: No, please don't misunderstand me. The question could certainly be the most important thing after vacuum cleaners. But if I can't figure out what the OP is talking about after a few minutes I begin to suspect something is wrong ..

Comment: @chuy Unfortunately, this does not work on the *original* data. This was my first guess too and for the simplified example it works. I edited the question again and pointed this out.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really blame the OP. After all, the docs [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/Graphics3D.html#1247190321) so glibly recommend that one now do `ListSurfacePlot3D[Flatten[pts, 1]]` where one once needed to do `ListSurfacePlot3D[pts]`.

We could, as halirutan did in his answer, grab the old routine from the package `` Graphics`Graphics3D` `` and just use it again in the new *Mathematica*. Or, we could exploit the fact that *Mathematica* now has `GraphicsComplex[]`, which lets us write a modernized version of Roman Maeder's `MakePolygons[]`:

```
MakePolygons[vl_] := Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]]}, 
  GraphicsComplex[Apply[Join, vl], Polygon[Flatten[Apply[Join[#1, Reverse[#2]] &, 
                  Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]], {2, 2}, {1, 1}],
                        {2}], 1]]]] /; ArrayQ[vl, 3]
```

which we can now use to turn the array of points into a nice pile of `Polygon[]`s:

```
data = Table[N[{2 z + Cos[φ], z, z + Sin[φ]}], {φ, 0, 2 π, π/30}, {z, -2, 2, 1/10}];

Graphics3D[MakePolygons[data]]
```

[image: skewed cylinder]

One does lose out on the options supported by the new `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` like coloring or texturing, but this might be offset by the comfort of seeing *Mathematica* dutifully render the mesh you expected and were supposed to see.

Comment: N.B. I previously used the version of `MakePolygons[]` featured here in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9259).