# Convert Tube[BSplineCurve[...]] Graphics3D object to polygons

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I wish to voxelize a complex shape composed of `Tube[BSplineCurve[...]]` objects, while maintaining the additional information of the (unvoxelated) surface normal directions at the surface voxels (for input into an already written C++ program).

I'll do the voxelization by repeating layer-by-layer rasterizations on 2D slices, similarly to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/how-to-convert-graphics3d-object-into-an-image3d-object). In order to do this elegantly, and especially to extract the surface normals from `VertexNormals` in a `GraphicsComplex`, I'd like to turn the `Tube[BSplineCurve[...]]` objects into a `GraphicsComplex` composed of polygons. This is the kind of thing that `Normal[ ]` is advertised to do, but I presume that the `BSplineCurve` being the centre of the tube throws it off.

Note that my question is superficially similar to [another that has been answered here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/convert-graphics3d-containing-bspline-to-polygon-primitives-for-export-to-3ds), but it relates to a surface built using `BSplineSurface`, whereas I want a `Tube` around a `BSplineCurve`. I don't know how to build the analogous `ParametricPlot3D` from J.M.'s answer there.

Minimal working example:

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};

FullForm[Graphics3D[Tube[BSplineCurve[pts]]]] (*and *)
FullForm[Normal@Graphics3D[Tube[BSplineCurve[pts]]]] (*both return*)
```

> ```
> Graphics3D[Tube[BSplineCurve[List[List[0, 0, 0], List[0, 1, 0], 
>                                   List[1, 1, 0], List[1, 1, 1]]]]]
> ```

rather than a `GraphicsComplex` composed of `Polygons`.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems what you are asking for has already been done by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/50) :) in [Extruding along a path](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452/5478):

Evaluate the definitions from the first `code block` up to `TubePolygons`.

Now, for the `Tube` you want a cross section which is a circle what can be done with `TubePolygons[path, 20, "Scale" -> .2]` or explicitly:

```
pointsPath = 10;
pointsCirc = 10;
radius = .1;
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
path = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot3D[BSplineFunction[pts][u] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}, 
                                      MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> pointsPath], 
                     Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

cs = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[radius {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                                  MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> pointsCirc], 
                   Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

Graphics3D[{TubePolygons[path, cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

---

Also closely related: [Plotting a 2D shape along a 3D parametric function curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29444/5478)