# Exporting BSplineSurface to STL

Tags: export, splines

I have encountered some difficulties getting `BSplineSurface` to export to STL.

The following code works and generates a triangulated polygon mesh from the NURBS spline (adapted from a `BSplineSurface` example):

```
cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}];
b = Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[cpts]]
Export["surface.stl", b, "STL"]
```

However, decreasing the number of control points in each dimension from **4** to **3**

```
cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
b = Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[cpts]]
Export["surface.stl", b, "STL"]
```

results in

```
GeometricFunctions`BSplineSurface::deglen: -- Message text not found -- (3)
Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the STL format. >>
$Failed
```

(Mathematica version 10).

Why is the success of exporting a `BSplineSurface` to STL dependent on the number of control points? Is there a reliable way to get arbitrary spline surfaces to export to STL? [Convert Graphics3D containing BSpline to polygon primitives for export to 3DS?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/convert-graphics3d-containing-bspline-to-polygon-primitives-for-export-to-3ds) seems somewhat related though not identical. I am aware that Mathematica cannot actually export NURBS surfaces, so a triangulation will suffice, just as it happens already for the surface with 16 control points.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/convert-graphics3d-containing-bspline-to-polygon-primitives-for-export-to-3ds) that you linked provides a way to export to `stl`.