# How to apply `DiscretizeGraphics` to a tube?

Tags: export, graphics3d, regions, discretization

I want to export the numerical solution of the Chan-Lee oscillator as an STL file so that I could print it out. But when I expanded the curve into a tube, `DiscretizeGraphics` recognizes it as an empty region. How could I somehow fill the tube and make it a discretizable solid?

My code:

```
α = 5; β = -10; δ = -.38;
s = NDSolve[{α x[t] - y[t] z[t] == 
 D[x[t], t], β y[t] + x[t] z[t] == 
 D[y[t], t], δ z[t] + x[t] y[t]/3 == D[z[t], t], 
x[0] == y[0] == z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}, 
MaxSteps -> ∞];

ps = Table[{x[t] - y[t]/Sqrt[2], y[t], z[t]} /. First[s], {t, 0, 
100, .1}];
curve = Graphics3D[Tube[BSplineCurve[ps], .5]];

Export["Chan-Lee.stl", DiscretizeGraphics[curve]]
```

Comment: Use `Cylinder` instead

Comment: Possible solution (work-around): [(9258)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9258/121), [(11452)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible workaround (brought up by the Wizard in the comments) involves the use of some of the functions from [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452). In particular, you will need `orthogonalDirections[]`, `extend[]`, and `crossSection[]` from that answer, along with these two additional functions for generating a suitable `MeshRegion[]` object:

```
MakeTriangleMesh[vl_List, opts___] := Module[{dims = Most[Dimensions[vl]]}, 
        MeshRegion[Apply[Join, vl], Triangle /@ Flatten[
                   Apply[{Append[Reverse[#1], Last[#2]], Prepend[#2, First[#1]]} &, 
                         Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]],
                                   {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}], 2], opts]] /; ArrayDepth[vl] == 3

TubeMesh[path_?MatrixQ, cs : (_Integer | _?MatrixQ), opts___] := 
    MakeTriangleMesh[FoldList[Function[{p, t}, With[{o = orthogonalDirections[t]},
                                       extend[#, t[[2]], t[[2]] - t[[1]], o] & /@ p]], 
                              crossSection[path, 1., cs],
                              Partition[path, 3, 1, {1, 2}, {}]], opts]
```

(The observant will notice that these are only slight modifications of the previous routines `MakePolygons[]` and `TubePolygons[]`.)

For your specific example:

```
With[{α = 5, β = -10, δ = -.38},
     {xx, yy, zz} = NDSolveValue[{α x[t] - y[t] z[t] == x'[t],
                                  β y[t] + x[t] z[t] == y'[t],
                                  δ z[t] + x[t] y[t]/3 == z'[t],
                                  x[0] == y[0] == z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}]]

path = Transpose[{{1/Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} .
                 Through[{xx, yy, zz}["ValuesOnGrid"]]];

TubeMesh[path, CirclePoints[0.5, 20]]
```

[image: a meshed tube]

Note that the result is an *open* tube (equivalent to using `CapForm[None]` with `Tube[]`); the equivalent of using `CapForm["Round"]` is slightly trickier to do.

Comment: I might try to come up with the "rounded ends" version later, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
RegionQ @ Cylinder[]
```

> True

```
RegionPlot3D @ Cylinder[]
```

**Output**

[image: cylinder]

```
RegionQ @ Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

> False

```
RegionPlot3D @ Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

**Output**

> {Tube[{{0,0,0},{1,1,1}}]} is not a valid region to plot.

**EDIT**

In order to achieve region look-a-like `Tube`, see implementation below.

**Example**

```
region = Fold[RegionUnion, 
    Ball[#1, #3], {Cylinder[{#1, #2}, #3], Ball[#2, #3]}] & [{0, 0, 
   0}, {10, 0, 0}, 1]
```

**Output**

```
RegionQ @ region
```

> True

```
RegionPlot3D @ region
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: But that way I could only get disconnected cylinders

Comment: You can always use `RegionUnion` to build-up the region in interest. I would also recommend to look at `Fold` you might find it useful.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. I meant to say that the join between two adjacent cylinders won't be rounded like `Tube`, and it's not that trivial to come up with a proper joining function suitable for display & printing.

Comment: No worries! Yes, I do appreciate the fact that you won't get the rounded top and the bottom when using a `Cylinder`. You could manipulate it further and construct a region using `Ball` and `Cylinder` this would allow you to get rounded top and bottom.