# How should a beginner figure out the context to use an expert answer provided on this forum?

Tags: graphics3d

[J.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452) to [Extruding along a path](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051) related to custom cross-sections appears to answer a question I have been puzzling over for some time.  I am interested in producing a tube with the stadium or stadion cross-section of oblong ductwork.  I look at the code and am lost as to how to use it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You only have to provide a path and a cross section to @J.M.'s `TubePolygons[]`. Please be more specific about your doubts.

Comment: Try `ListPlot@cs` you can see the cross section @J.M is using! So what you need to do is discretize your custom cross-section into some 2D points and declare it as `cs`. And you will be done.

Comment: +1 simply for drawing my attention to a really cool answer I'd previously missed

Answer (score 14):

I'll just dissect a little [@J.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452/193) for you:

First define a path:

```
path = ParametricPlot3D[
        BSplineFunction[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, -1}, {3, 0, 1}, {4, 1, -1}}][u] 
                        // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now extract the `Line[]` definitions from that plot:

```
pathL = First@Cases[path, Line[l_] :> l, Infinity]
```

Do the same with the cross section:

```
cs = ParametricPlot[BSplineFunction[{{0., 0.}, {1/4, 0.}, {1/2, 1/8}, {1/4, 1/4}, {0., 1/4}},
                            SplineClosed -> True][u] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion->1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Get those lines:

```
csL = First@Cases[cs, Line[l_] :> l, Infinity]
```

Now use [@JM's function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452/193):

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[pathL, csL]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Another example:

```
path = First@Cases[ParametricPlot3D[5 {Sin[u u], Cos[u u], u}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                                    MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];

cs = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}};

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...And a last one:

```
path = First@ Cases[ParametricPlot3D[5 {Sin[u ], Cos[u ], 0}, {u, 0, Pi}, 
                    MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];

cs = First@ Cases[ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 u], Cos@u}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                  MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's great, Belisarius, got it to work. Many thanks. Any thoughts on how to make TubePolygons have the equivalent of CapForm["Round"] for Tube?

Comment: @rexacoatl That doesn't seem trivial at all