# Plotting a 2D shape along a 3D parametric function curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Say I have a 3D curve that is parametrically defined. How would I be able to plot shapes like figure 8's whose centers are aligned along the 3D curve?

Say the curve was:

```
P[a_] := {-a, a, 1/2 a (8 - a)};
arch = ParametricPlot3D[P[a], {a, 0, 8}, Axes -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
                        PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this, you could use the answer by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452/245) to the question ["Extruding along a path"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3051/245). The question here isn't a duplicate because it makes use of features in J.M.'s excellent answer that go beyond what the linked question actually asked for. In particular, that answer can deal with self-intersecting cross sectional curves, which is what you need **for this question**:

So what you have to do is: first copy the definitions in J.M.'s answer and then define your custom cross section:

```
cs = First@
   Cases[ParametricPlot[
     BSplineFunction[{{0., 0.}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.}, {0., 0.25}},
         SplineClosed -> True][u] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: tube]

For your arch example, it looks like this:

```
P[a_] := {-a, a, 1/2 a (8 - a)};
path = First@
   Cases[ParametricPlot3D[P[a], {a, 0, 8}, MaxRecursion -> 1], 
    Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], TubePolygons[path, 5 cs]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: arch]

**Edit: discrete shapes**

Here is a discrete version where the shapes are inserted at positions given in a table. For the math behind the rotation transformation, have a look at ["Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18598/245):

```
figureEight = 
 ParametricPlot[
  BSplineFunction[{-{0.25, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.25}, {0.25, -.25}, {-.25, 
       0.25}}, SplineClosed -> True][u] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image: eight]

```
cs = First @ Cases[figureEight, Line[l_] :> l, ∞];

Clear[t];

r[t_] := P[t]

uT[t_] = Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t ∈ Reals];

vN[t_] = Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t ∈ Reals];

vB[t_] = Simplify[Cross[uT[t], vN[t]], t ∈ Reals];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {P[t]}, {t, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}],
 Table[
  Graphics3D[{
    Translate[
     GeometricTransformation[Tube@Line[Map[Append[#, 0] &, 10 cs]], 
      Transpose[{vN[s], vB[s], uT[s]}]], P[s]]}], {s, 0, 8}], 
 PlotRange -> 10 {{-1.1, .2}, {-.2, 1.1}, {-.2, 1.1}}]
```

[image: 3d]

The matrix in `GeometricTransformation` is made up of the three unit vectors tangent, normal, and bi-normal to the arc curve. The figure-eight shape is centered at the origin in a 2D coordinate system, so we have to first use `Append` to add a z-coordinate `0` to its points, and then align the orthogonal Cartesian axes with the normal and bi-normal vectors at a given point along the curve. Finally,  the whole shape is translated to the location `P[s]` where `s` is the curve parameter.

Comment: Of course I may be misunderstanding the question. Maybe the "shapes" are supposed to be discrete. But in the absence of a specific statement, I assumed the shapes are as continuous as the path itself.

Comment: Yes I meant that the shapes would be discrete and that maybe i could specify the interval on which they appear. By my intuition I figured I should find an equation for the planes perpendicular to the curve at all points and then write a formula for the shape on those planes. I just dont know how to go about doing this.

Comment: I updated the answer with a discrete version of the shape.

Answer (score 5):

A version 10 approach:

```
tnb[g_, t_] := Last@FrenetSerretSystem[g[t], t]
func[g_, t_, pc_, s_] := 
 Line[g[t] + # & /@ ((Plus @@ (tnb[g, v] #) & /@ 
       Table[PadLeft[s pc[j], 3], {j, 0, 1, 0.05}]) /. v -> t)]
```

Some test functions:

```
arc[t_] := {-t, t, 1/2 t (8 - t)};
helix[t_] := {Cos[ 2 t], Sin[ 2 t], 0.25 t}

f[u_] := BSplineFunction[{-{0.25, 0.25}, {0.25, 
      0.25}, {0.25, -.25}, {-.25, 0.25}}, SplineClosed -> True][u];
circ[u_] := {Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi u]};
```

Testing:

```
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[fu[t], {t, 0, 10}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, func[fu, par, pc, sc]}], 
  PlotRange -> Table[{-r, r}, {3}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> Black],
 {fu, {arc, helix}}, {pc, {f -> "Figure of eight", 
   circ -> "Circle"}}, {sc, 0.1, 5}, {par, 0, 10}, {{r, 10, "range"}, 
  4, 12}]
```

[image]

Not an ideal gif but perhaps sufficient to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

The routines in the answer Jens linked to can still be used if you just want to lay slices across your arch. Here is how to use them:

```
arch = Table[{-a, a, 1/2 a (8 - a)}, {a, 0, 8}];
figureEight = First @ Cases[ParametricPlot[
                    BSplineFunction[{-{0.25, 0.25}, {0.25, 0.25},
                                     {0.25, -.25}, {-.25, 0.25}}, SplineClosed -> True][u]
                    // Evaluate,
                                           {u, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1], Line[l_] :> l, 
                            Infinity];

slices = FoldList[Function[{p, t}, 
                           With[{o = orthogonalDirections[t]}, 
                                extend[#, t[[2]], t[[2]] - t[[1]], o] & /@ p]], 
                  crossSection[arch, 10, figureEight], 
                  Partition[arch, 3, 1, {1, 2}, {}]];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{-a, a, 1/2 a (8 - a)}, {a, 0, 8}, 
                      PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]],
     Graphics3D[Tube /@ slices], 
     PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1.3, 2.4, 2.}]
```

[image: lemniscates on an arch]