# ParametricPlot3D won't show

Tags: plotting, vector

I want to see the image of a tube made from a space curve. I define the surface using Frenet-Serret frame but the software does not show me the plot. What might be wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the code for the plot please, thx

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps adding the underscores in the definition of T2 might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extruding along a path](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/extruding-along-a-path)

Comment: It is not because I wasn't looking for the use of Tube command, I needed a mathematical expression.

Comment: Not all the answers use `Tube` but plot a shape (e.g. a circle) normal to a parametrized path.  Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29444/plotting-a-2d-shape-along-a-3d-parametric-function-curve, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/moving-polygon-on-path-curve-to-create-3d-shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `c` and to use the correct syntax in the definition of `T2`:

```
T2[s_, y_] := r[s] + 2*(c[s]*Sin[y] - j[s]*Cos[y])
c[s_] := s; (* for example *)
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@T2[s, y], {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]

Update: For the updated version of the question:

```
ClearAll[r, s, j, v, T2, y]
r[s_] := {-(5 + 2*Cos[2*s])*Sin[3*s], (5 + 2*Cos[2*s])*Cos[3*s], 
  2*Sin[2*s]}
j[s_] := Normalize[Cross[r'[s], r''[s]]]
v[s_] := Normalize[Cross[j[s], Normalize[r'[s]]]]
T2[s_, y_] := r[s] + 1*(j[s]*Sin[y] - v[s]*Cos[y])

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@T2[s, y], {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]