# Moving polygon on path curve to create 3D shape

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I move some polygon

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 15}, {7, 13}, {2, 13}, {2, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 3}, {2,3}, {2, 0}};
Graphics[{Black, Polygon[list]}]
```

so it follow some 3D parametric curve

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], 5 Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}]
```

to create 3D shape?
The tangent of the curve should be always perpendicular to polygon surface. So I could create, for example, the 3D shape like this [image]

Comment: J. M. answered this question here.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/extruding-along-a-path

Comment: To the closers: not sure if this is a duplicate, since the mentioned question does not explicitly ask for arbitrary cross-section for the loft (although [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50569/131) adresses the issue).

Comment: @Yves: Perhaps one could edit the previous question to *optionally* request an arbitrary cross-section. (That wouldn't invalidate the rest of the existing answers.)

Comment: @Rahul not sure - most answers (also the accepted answer) deal with circular tubes...

Comment: Is there anybody could help to adopt the answer to polygons as the cross section?

Comment: @YvesKlett I have an answer ready for this post. It is not obvious for the OP to deduce the answer by himself from the related post. (already flagged this post with this same message but I don't know if it was to right way to ask for the reopen of the question.)

Comment: @SquareOne super - I voted to reopen, probably other will chime in as well (hopefully). Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @SquareOne Reopened on request.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков In J.M.'s answer linked by David G. Stork, `cs` is just the coordinates of the polygon being extruded.  For `cs` use you `list`.  I'd suggest trying `cs = list/50` because your polygon is way too big for the path you have.  See ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xjAhr.png)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It does seem like a duplicate to me.  One problem is that J.M. gave a much more general answer to a question that has specific focus that is a difference from this one. However SquareOne could answer the other question, using a regular polygon for the circle as well as show the generality of his or her method with an arbitrary polygon.  And potentially earn a Necromancer badge to boot.  Just an idea.  It keeps the alternatives for this sort of thing from being scattered about the site.

Comment: @MichaelE2 As a matter of policy I try to reopen when people have an answer waiting.  If after it is posted it looks like an answer to the original I can merge this one into that which will move the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree it's a good policy.  Somehow I just thought I should notify you.  I'm hoping SquareOne will see my comments and decide where it is best to post an answer. (Not knowing what it is, I can't say for sure what should happen, which is why I haven't voted to close yet.)

Comment: @SquareOne Please see my comments.  I think they may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for reopening the post. Please see my answer.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for your vote to reopen the post. Please see my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My approach is based on the basic Frenet Trihedron formulas (which were implemented in v.10) and also some basic geometric transformations (matrix rotation and translation).

It can be applied to extrude any 2D polygon.

### 1. Choice of the path

I modified a little bit the OP's path for the sake of keeping the 3D graphics simple to view.

```
path[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/2};

{uStart, uEnd} = {0, 2};
```

It corresponds to a portion of a helix

```
gPath = ParametricPlot3D[path[u], {u, uStart - 0.2, uEnd + 0.2}, 
PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02]]
```

[image]

### 2. Choice of the Polygon

This is the OP's polygon :

```
list = {{0, 0}, {0, 15}, {7, 13}, {2, 13}, {2, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 3}, {2,3}, {2,0}};
```

which needs to be scaled down in order to fit the overall size of the path. For example :

```
scale = 0.05;
transxy = {-0.05, -0.25};
(nlist = (Plus[transxy, #] & /@ (scale*list))) // 
 Graphics[{Black, Polygon[#]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}] &
```

Notice the arbitrary translation (`transxy`) which lets you also choose where exactly the path line will pass through the polygon (we defined here the axes origin `{0,0}` to be always this point). (Of course, one could also add a local rotation of the polygon in the plane if needed).

[image]

### 3. Transformation Definitions (Rotation+Translation)

To extrude the polygon along the path, we need to rotate the 2D polygon in the 3D space such that its (x,y) axes match respectively the (normal, binormal) axes of the frenet trihedron along the curve. The z axis will have to match the tangent of the curve (in order this tangent to be perpendicular to the polygon surface as requested by the OP). We also need to translate the rotated polygon to its corresponding position along the path.

All this can be simply achieved with :

```
frenet[u_] = FrenetSerretSystem[path[u], u][[2]];

transform[u_] := Composition[TranslationTransform[path[u]], 
 FindGeometricTransform[frenet[u], {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}][[2]]]
```

### 4. Extruding Points

```
(* Here you choose how many extruded polygons you want along the given path *)
nint = 50;

allpoints = 
 Table[transform[u] /@ (nlist /. {x_, y_} -> {x, y, 0}),
{u, uStart, uEnd, (uEnd - uStart)/nint}];
```

Let's check :

```
Graphics3D[{Point /@ allpoints, Polygon@allpoints[[1]]}]
```

[image]

### 5. Drawing the surface

That's almost it ... We "just" need to draw some surface passing through the "extruded" points.

#### 5.1 The hard way

The idea here is simply to draw polygons through every 4 neighbour points.

```
pPoly = Join[allpoints, List /@ allpoints[[All, 1]], 2] // 
   Table[Polygon@Extract[#, { {i, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i + 1, j + 1}, {i + 1, j}}],
 {i, 1, Length@# - 1}, {j, 1, Length@#[[1]] - 1}] &;
pPolyEnds = allpoints // {First@#, Last@#} & // Polygon;
pEdges = Line[Transpose@allpoints];
pExtr = {RGBColor[0.8, 0.8, 0.8], {EdgeForm[], 
    pPoly}, {EdgeForm[Black], pPolyEnds}, {Black, pEdges}};
```

The final result :

```
gTNB = Graphics3D@Map[Arrow@{path[0.], path[0.] + #} &, frenet[0.]];

Show[{Graphics3D@pExtr, gPath, gTNB}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

In particular, you can check here that 1/ the path (in blue) pass through the chosen point inside the polygon (see the section *Choice of the polygon*), and 2/ that the polygon surface is perpendicular to tangent and that the (x,y) axes of the polygon matches the normal and binormal directions.

#### 5.2 The Spline Way

You can attempt to draw directly the surface passing through all the "extruded" points with the function `BSplineSurface`:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.8]], 
  BSplineSurface[allpoints, SplineDegree -> 1]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

However, if you look carefully there is a problem because some edges are not anymore sharp as they should be. If you zoom in :

[image]

The workaround is simply to break the whole surface into smaller parts (which solves also the problem to draw solid lines along the edges of the polygon).

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[GrayLevel[0.8]], 
  allpoints // {First@#, Last@#} & // Polygon, 
  BSplineSurface[#, SplineDegree -> 1] & /@ 
   Partition[Transpose@Join[allpoints, List /@ allpoints[[All, 1]], 2], 2, 1]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

You can have a much smoother 3D rendering of the surface if you use `SplineDegree->2` (it is safe to do so because we have broken the whole surface into smaller smooth parts) :

[image]

This last graphic shows that one could optimize `nint`, the number of extruded points, in order to get the smoothest surface with the less number of these points.

Comment: There are of course few things to improve. 1/I am not satisfied yet with the way `transform` is defined. 2/The extruded points could be computed as a function of the curvature in order to add more points where needed, like in the `Plot*` functions. 3/ It would be nice to have a `BSplineSurface` which simply draws a surface between two given curves (here those curves are known : this is simply the translated `path[u]` for each point of the polygon) ...

Comment: For some paths it does not work properly path[u_] := {20 Sin[u]^0.01, 20 Cos[u]^0.01, 0}

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков The problem does not come from the approach. You have to carefully examine the particular path you've chosen. 1/ Sin[u] and Cos[u] can't return negative numbers otherwise you'll get complex numbers ... 2/ but it seems also that Mathematica has a problem to compute the tangent, normal and binormal at u=0,Pi/2,Pi, ... I could extrude with no problem just defining `{uStart, uEnd} = {0.001, Pi/2};`