# Why Interpolation is slower than BSplineFunction?

Tags: performance-tuning, interpolation, splines

This my question is concerned with previous about [Tube cross-section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133311/). Let's use the same `pts` as in that question.

```
pts = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {7.497665500157259`*^-14, 
   0.00036555534709634656`, 
   0.041887873232098444`}, {2.9988378071419946`*^-13, 
   0.0014621100333863195`, 
   0.08376298663421493`}, {6.746528662189823`*^-13, 
   0.0032893300277940163`, 
   0.12561258426325045`}, {1.1991697498398906`*^-12, 
   0.005846658724918654`, 
   0.16742391794868797`}, {1.8732746539195436`*^-12, 
   0.009133317114586991`, 
   0.20918425117592362`}, {2.696762233490476`*^-12, 
   0.013148304019154402`, 
   0.25088086296604745`}, {3.669381638827055`*^-12, 
   0.017890396398482316`, 
   0.2925010517508915`}, {4.790836591859004`*^-12, 
   0.02335814972249914`, 
   0.33403213924216535`}, {6.0607854764232425`*^-12, 
   0.029549898411231134`, 
   0.37546147429349974`}, {7.478841442326563`*^-12, 
   0.03646375634216925`, 
   0.41677643675422266`}, {9.044572523187444`*^-12, 
   0.04409761742481735`, 
   0.45796444131369324`}, {1.0757501768021084`*^-11, 
   0.052449156242246726`, 
   0.499012941335023`}, {1.26171073865276`*^-11, 0.06151582875946169`,
    0.5399094326770161`}, {1.4622822908039118`*^-11, 
   0.07129487309836018`, 
   0.5806414575031648`}, {1.6774037354077335`*^-11, 
   0.08178331037905351`, 0.6211966080765395`}, {1.9070095424469`*^-11,
    0.09297794562728895`, 
   0.6615625305394178`}, {2.1510297696962602`*^-11, 
   0.10487536874769866`, 
   0.7017269286765003`}, {2.4093900840285483`*^-11, 
   0.11747195556257856`, 
   0.7416775676605682`}, {2.6820117840576448`*^-11, 
   0.13076386891588063`, 
   0.7814022777794407`}, {2.9688118241124915`*^-11, 
   0.14474705984208247`, 0.8208889581430966`}}
```

Now I need to construct parametric form of the curve. One method is using `Interpolation`:

```
path[u_] = Interpolation[#, u] & /@ Transpose[pts]
```

The main advantage of `Interpolation` is that `path` is going through all the points of `pts` exactly. Then I use code from @SquareOne:

```
frenet[u_] = FrenetSerretSystem[path[u], u][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
transform[u_] := 
  Composition[TranslationTransform[pts[[u]]], 
   FindGeometricTransform[
     frenet[u], {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}][[2]]];
```

I included `AbsoluteTiming` here to measure time of operation. And I see that `frenet[u_]` takes significant time, about 0.27--0.3 sec on my machine.

Another approach is using `BSplineFunction`:

```
path1[u_] := BSplineFunction[#][u] & /@ (Transpose@pts);
frenet1[u_] = FrenetSerretSystem[path1[u], u][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This is much faster, it takes about 0.09--0.1 sec on my machine, i.e. `BSplineFunction` is 2.5--3 times faster than `Interpolation`. Why is this difference in speed? Can I speed-up `Interpolation` if I want to use it because of (as I think, probably wrong) it gives more accurate approximation.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you use `Method -> "Spline"` in `Interpolation[]`?

Comment: If I run `path[u_] = Interpolation[#, u, Method -> "Spline"] & /@ Transpose[pts]`, then `frenet[u_]` takes about 0.32--0.35 sec, more or the same time or even longer.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to speed up the construction of the code generated by `FrenetSerretSystem`, which is done only once for each set of `pts`?  `Interpolation` itself is fast, but it is `FrenetSerretSystem` that takes the extra time when analyzing (I surmise) `InterpolatingFunction` compared to analyzing `BSplineFunction`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, right. I have many such sets of points, and I had a hope it is possibe to decrease time of these operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: [`FrenetSerretSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html) seems to take a symbolic approach, which slows it down.  A more straightforward numeric approach, which will be much faster, may be more satisfactory.

The following function works for all (twice differentiable) paths.  The savings are two-fold. One doesn't have to compute a new Frenet frame function for each set of points; only an interpolating path needs to be computed. Second, as seen below, this function executes faster than the one created with `FrenetSerretFrame[]` in the OP.

```
ClearAll[frenet2];
fsfC = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {a, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{nv, na},
    If[v == {0, 0, 0},                        (* singular point *)
     {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
     nv = v * Internal`ReciprocalSqrt[v.v];   (* use v / Sqrt[v.v] pre V10 *)
     If[a == {0, 0, 0},                       (* no turning *)
      {nv, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
      na = # * Internal`ReciprocalSqrt[#.#] &[a - (a.nv) nv];
      {nv, na, Cross[nv, na]}
      ]]
    ]];
frenet2[path_, {u_, u0_?NumericQ}] :=
  With[{v = D[path, u]}, With[{a = D[v, u]}, Block[{u = u0},
     fsfC[v, a]
     ]]];
```

Using a single `InterpolatingFunction` instead of three seems to speed things up a little, too:

```
path2[u_] = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, pts]][u]
```

[image]

*Timings.* Note that `frenet2` works on the OP's paths.  The frame is slightly different for `path1` because the B-spline path is slightly different from the interpolated path.

```
uu0 = 12.5;
frenet2[path[u], {u, uu0}] // RepeatedTiming
frenet2[path1[u], {u, Rescale[uu0, {1, 21}]}] // RepeatedTiming
frenet2[path2[u], {u, uu0}] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.00013,
    {{4.08916*10^-11, 0.199371, 0.979924},
     {2.00986*10^-10, 0.979924, -0.199371},
     {-1., 2.05103*10^-10, 1.9387*10^-26}}}

  {0.00016,
    {{4.03653*10^-11, 0.196805, 0.980443},
     {2.01092*10^-10, 0.980443, -0.196805},
     {-1., 2.05103*10^-10, 9.69352*10^-26}}}

  {0.000077,
    {{4.08916*10^-11, 0.199371, 0.979924},
     {2.00986*10^-10, 0.979924, -0.199371},
     {-1., 2.05103*10^-10, 1.9387*10^-26}}}
*)
```

The first and third `frenet2` frames agree with the frame computed by `FrenetSerretFrame` used in the OP's `frenet`; they're also much faster than `frenet`:

```
frenet[uu0] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.0011,
    {{4.08916*10^-11, 0.199371, 0.979924},
     {2.00986*10^-10, 0.979924, -0.199371},
     {-1., 2.05103*10^-10, 1.28793*10^-26}}
*)
```

Comment: many thanks! This works very fast!

Comment: sorry for late question, had no time. As I undestand, in your `fsfC` parameters `nv` and `na` are normalized. So we can write `nv = Normalize[v]`, and `na = Normalize[a - (a.nv) nv]`. This works. Next step is replace `(a.nv) nv` with `Projection[a, nv]`, and this gives me errors that parameters have different rank and uncompiled function will be used. What is wrong? I read many times that one shoud preferably use built-in functions, they are extremely optimized.

Comment: @Alx: Yes, built-in are often (should be always but in practice not) to be preferred.  If we're using `Compile`, then we should use functions built into the compiler.  Execute the following: ``Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]``; then `CompilePrint@Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {w, _Real, 1}}, Projection[v, w]]` and `CompilePrint@Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}}, Normalize[v]]`. They show `MainEvaluate[..]` called on `Projection` and `Normalize`, which means the functions are [not "compilable"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/).....

Comment: @Alx ...Further `Compile` has no (internal) declared return type for `Normalize[]`, so it assumes it returns a real number. You can declare the return type by added a declaration at the end: `fsfC = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {a, _Real, 1}}, Block[{nv, na},,,], {{Normalize[_], _Real, 1}}]`.  See "Compiled Function Operation" in the [compiler manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html). Just to be clear, the use of `Projection` and `Normalize` inside `Compile` should be slower.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I've read topic on List of compilable functions and the main conclusion (as I understood) is that (in most cases) simple ("low-level") functions such as `Sin` or `Dot` can be used in `Compile`, but not "high-level" already optimized ones as e.g. `NIntegrate` or `Projection`.