# Using Plot 3D to create Ice Cream Cone

Tags: plotting

[image: ice cream cone]

How might I recreate this ice cream using Plot3D
given:

```
cone = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

and below the spherical cap:
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 50
```

[image: Double Integral and Evaluation]

Comment: is there a variation of this without contour but only using Plot3D etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just sawthe text before only.

Comment: This is a type of often asked question. Nice concept is probable this: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69831/moving-polygon-on-path-curve-to-create-3d-shape/69969#69969]. Solution is `Show[Graphics3D[{Yellow, Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1]}], 
 Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2] + 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], Mesh -> 8, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}]]` or use `Plot3D[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]` for the cone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot3D[{2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]-4, Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}]
```