# Export Tube with VertexColors to 3DS

Tags: export, graphics3d

I would like to export a `Tube` object with `VertexColors` defined to 3DS format. Here's a minimum example:

```
test = Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Blue}]]
Export["test.3ds", test, "3DS"]
```

However, it appears that `Tube` objects are only exportable if they lack the `VertexColors` option, this seems to be true for all 3D formats. It seems to me that the simplest solution is to convert a graphic with `Tube` objects into the `GraphicsComplex` format, which does support `VertexColors` upon export.

I'm guessing it might only be possible to use one of [the old "extrude" solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/extruding-along-a-path) to this problem prior to the `Tube` primitive existing. Is this the only way to do it? If so, how can `VertexColors` be added to the extrusion methods of old? I'll note that the extrusion method produces 3D surfaces with far more polygons than `Tube` does, and with weird vertex normals. This makes the exported objects unnecessarily large and kinda ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The Mathematica Package below exports to either of two popular raytracer file formats (not 3ds which is proprietary/binary), and can be used Live in Mathematica interactively/Live.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rayshade-math/

I'm interested myself if anyone is exporting to a Cuda rendering suite or even 3DStudio ARt Renderer and how well Export[] did (in the past export was very poor, i have no copy of 3dstudio to check today's results - but do not have fingers crossed since Wolfram only shows pics being exported not their results?)

Mathematica has import/export to institutional formats for geo mapping and chemical. For most, those are the work-horses and more the focus - but i have no idea there how well mm does exporting. Importing wise, Mathematica can use maps we all know that!

[image: a busy cat]
[image: rayshade-mathematica]