# How to create the new CDF logo by Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d

I am very curious about the CDF logo,  can anyone tell me how is it made? is it made by Mathematica? Does anyone give me any tips?

[image]

Comment: It's a `ParametricPlot3D` with some kind of spiral defined by one parameter and the other tracing out a triangle whose size varies with position of the spiral. And then the same thing rotated and a bit of fiddling with `Specularity`. The exact curves weren't obvious to me so I'll leave it for others to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Verbeia

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50569/4999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extruding along a path](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/extruding-along-a-path)