# Tubes on spiral - Graphics 3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Now I am working on something like this:

```
helix[a_, b_][t_] := {a*Cos[t], a*Sin[t], b*t}    
listept1 = Table[helix[1, 0.35][t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, .25}];
listept2 = Table[helix[0.25, 0.35][t], {t, 0, 4 Pi, .25}];
mapdecalgarde = Map[{0, 0, 0.5} + # &, {listept1}, {2}];
exterieurSup1 = Map[{0, 0, 0.1} + # &, listept1];
mapdecalgarde1 = Map[{0, 0, 0.5} + # &, listept1];
Listedepointgardecorps1 = 
Flatten[{{mapdecalgarde1}, {exterieurSup1}}, 1];
ptsGarCor1 = Transpose[Listedepointgardecorps1];
ligneGardeCor1 = Map[Line, ptsGarCor1];
barriere = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.25], RGBColor[1, 3, 0], Tube[ptsGarCor1]}]
```

and simple rods I want to substitute with this particular shape:

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Round"], Tube[{{0, 100, 0}, {100, 300, 0}, {300, 300, 100}}, 40]},  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

in this orientation:

[image]

so it freely rotates around (let say) Z direction where XY plane alongside the twofold symmetry axis.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to substitute ordinary rods with bent-core rods (on spiral)?

Comment: Your  `helix[ ]` lacks the definition

Comment: I have edited the code and added definition of `helix[]` (which I have previously forgot to include).

Comment: Like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/extruding-along-a-path)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 rather like this [link](http://www.tinypic.pl/wby03qbh6zm2)

Comment: But you already have my answer to your previous question. This is the same problem, another banana.

Comment: And BTW read carefully the following comment

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wanting the kinks to point directly away from the z-axis? If not I'll remove this answer.

```
carat[{{x_, y_, z1_}, {x_, y_, z2_}}] := 
 Translate[
  Rotate[Translate[
    Tube[{{x, y, z1}, {x + (z2 - z1)/4 Sqrt[3/7], y, (z1 + z2)/2}, {x, y, z2}}, 
     (z2 - z1)/10], {-x, -y, 0}], π + ArcTan[x, y], {0, 0, 1}], {x, y, 0}]

Graphics3D[{CapForm["Round"], Opacity[0.25], RGBColor[1, 3, 0], 
  carat /@ ptsGarCor1}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I want to recreate something like this [Link](http://iv.pl/images/36628805736688853453.png)

Comment: @ATomek as far as I can tell, that's what I think my solution does.