# How to pre or post process KnotData "substrate"

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, knots

What I'm after might be thought of as operating on the 'rope' that `KnotData[]` uses. Specifically, I'd like to be able to specify that the knot is to be made of a prism (not the *Mathematica* `Prism[]`, which is always triangular) whose cross section could be a not-necessarily-regular $n$-gon, and could be twisted *a la* the Möbius strip.  Looking at the daunting appearance of the `InputForm[]` of `KnotData[]` convinces me that polygonalization and twisting steps should precede `KnotData[]` - but how?

Here is the `InputForm[]` structure for several knots (e.g., Torus, Trefoil)

```
Graphics3D[{{GraphicsComplex[{{-0.53993, -0.00924, 0.16395}, ... ,
                           {-0.50971, 0.00165, 0.07456}}, 
{{{EdgeForm[],
    GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{1, 2, 14, 13}, ... , 
                             {8820, 8809, 8821, 8832}}]}]}, {}}}, 
VertexNormals -> {{0.00026, -0.18488, 0.98276}, ...,
                  {0.60404, 0.15619, -0.78149}}]}}, 
{Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {All, All, All}, PlotRangePadding -> 
{Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0.01, 5}}]
```

Notes: `Tube` seems to be the default (whether explicitly specified, or not, as in the above).  Documentation, i.e.,  [ref/KnotData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KnotData.html), shows the use of `Sphere` to accomplish a similar goal. And, speaking of docs, there seems to be an omission:
Below list of Classes omits  `"Ribbon"`, `"Slice"`, and `"Twist"` though all three are included in the "Basic classes of knots"  in ref/KnotData.   Both `"Alternating"` and `"Nonalternating"` are listed as `"Basics"`, though it appears that `"Nonalternating"` should be with the other Non's in "Negative classes of knots."

```
KnotData["Classes"]

{"Alternating", "Amphichiral", "Chiral", "Composite", "Hyperbolic",
"Invertible", "Nonalternating", "Nonhyperbolic", "Noninvertible",
"Nonsatellite", "Nontorus", "Prime", "Satellite", "Torus"}
```

Lastly, I obviously haven't gotten the hang of Markdown yet.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is basically @TeakeNutma's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50569/45431) to [Extruding along a path](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3051/45431), but modified to allow arbitrary n-gons as the cross section. First, here is one way to obtain a parametrized n-gon. Suppose the points making up the 2D n-gon are given in a list `pts`. For example:

```
pts = {{1, 0}, {-1/2, 1}, {-1/2, -1}};
```

Then, you can parametrize the n-gon by creating a 3D [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction):

```
poly = Interpolation[
    Thread[{
        Range[0, Length[pts]],
        PadRight[pts, {Length[pts]+1, 3}, PadRight[pts[[1]], 3]]
    }],
    InterpolationOrder->1
];
```

Let's check out the 2D projection of this [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction):

```
ParametricPlot[poly[t][[;;2]], {t, 0, Length[pts]}]
```

[image]

The space curve for a knot can be obtained using the "SpaceCurve" property:

```
knot = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"]
```

> {Sin[#1] + 2 Sin[2 #1], Cos[#1] - 2 Cos[2 #1], -Sin[3 #1]} &

Now, we use `poly` and `knot` to create your graphic:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    knot[u] + 1/8 RotationMatrix[{{0,0,1},knot'[u]}] . poly[v],
    {u,0,2 Pi},
    {v,0,3},
    Exclusions->None, Boxed->False, Axes->False, Mesh->False, PlotPoints->40
]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  These functions (and ideas) will give me something to gnaw on for a couple weeks.